# Rudin Functional Analysis Ex. 4 Ch. 2 Application of uniform boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Show that $L^2(0,1)$ is of first category in $L^1(0,1)$ by doing the following

Let $$g_n(t):=\begin{cases}n&,0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{n^3}\\0&,\frac{1}{n^3}<t\leq 1\end{cases}$$

and show that $$\int_0^1f(t)g_n(t)dt\to 0\ \forall\ f \in L^2(0,1)\ \mathrm{but\ not\ for\ every}\ f \in L^1(0,1)$$

> My try:

By using Holder's inequality and integrating I arrive at
$$|\int_0^1f(t)g_n(t)dt|\leq (\int_0^1f(t)^2dt)^{1/2}(\int_0^1g_n(t)^2dt)^{1/2}=\|f\|_2\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$$

So $|\int_0^1f(t)g_n(t)dt| \to 0\  \forall\ f \in L^2(0,1)$

Let $$\phi_n:L^1(0,1)\to\mathbb R\\\phi_n(f):=\int_0^1f(t)g_n(t)dt$$, then $\phi_n$ is linear and bounded because $\|\phi_n(f)\|=\|g\|_\infty=n$

So if we assume that $\phi_n(f)\to 0\ \forall\ f \in L^1(0,1)$ then there has to exist (according to principle of uniform boundedness) a $C \geq 0$ such that $\|\phi_n\|\leq C\ \forall\ n \in \mathbb N$ but as $\|\phi_n\|=n$ can become arbitrarily large, this is a contradiction.

**>How does this show that $L^2(0,1)$ is of first category in $L^1(0,1)$?**

I also tried to understand the following proof: The author doesn't just simply assume that $\phi_n(f)\to 0\ \forall\ f \in L^1(0,1)$ *but says that it follows from the principle of uniform boundedness if we make the assumption that* $L^2(0,1)$ *is of 2nd category*. Then I understand how the contradiction proves, that it is of first category.

> **But why does it follow from the principle of uniform boundedness if we make the assumption that $L^2(0,1)$ is of 2nd category?**

[image]